# iOS: Strategies for downloading very large data from web

Tags: ios, swift, memory, nsurlsession

I'm struggling with memory management in iOS while downloading relatively large files from the web (such as videos with 350MB size).
The goal here is to download these kind of files and store it on CoreData on a Binary Data field.

At the moment I'm using `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithUrl` and `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest` methods to retrieve these files, but it looks like these methods don't treat problems such as memory usage, they just keep on filling the memory until it reaches its maximum usage, leaving me with a memory warning when I reach 380MB~.

[Initial Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShOaM.png)

[Memory Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Vfy.png)

What's the best strategy to perform this kind of large data retrieval from the web without reaching a memory warning? Does AlamoFire and other libs can deal with this problem?

Comment: What if you use a download task instead of a data task?  Is there any particular need to have your download in memory?

Comment: Well, I guess you'll have to agree with me when I say that I'll have to have it on the memory when the time to save on CoreData comes. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I can't imagine saving something that size inside a CoreData object.  Obviously I don't know your app but I would be more likely to save the video as a file and put its path or URL into CoreData.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but, when you say "save the video as a file and put its path to CoreData" were you suggesting to save it on the DocumentsDirectory or on the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Either documents or some other part of your writable sandbox.  NSUserDefaults are also not good for large pieces of data.

Comment: After doing a quick search, I found out that there's special directory called <Application_Home>/Library/Caches. I'll try to implement this persistence with the "do-not-backup" option to keep it persisted as stated here https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is better to use download task.

And save the video as a file to **Document** or **Library** directory.

Then save the relative path to CoreData

If you use download task

- You can resume if last download fail
- Need less memory

Comment: This is really the best way to handle large files that aren't passable data (i.e. JSON or XML).  Don't hang onto the data in memory at all but write the data directly to disk as it is received.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the explanation. I feel like this is solved :)

Answer (score -3):

You can try [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to download large files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it!

Comment: Please include some details about the solution.  Link only answers lose their value when the link is gone.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but more a "let someone else do the hard work" response with just a link.  When an OP is asking *how* to do something it is best to discuss the hows instead of just pointing to a third party library.