# Best way to stream/download large data on first launch

Tags: ios, on-demand-resources, app-thinning

Here is my conundrum: I have a WalkthroughViewController that appears on the very first launch of the app. The app itself has a vast amount of features, one that requires a fair bit of explanation to the average *webdev* beginner.

I have managed to create **4 videos** that quickly summarize the app, as well as its tools. The videos are 1080p screen captures that manage to makeup roughly **147MB**.

I know that there are a few different options, one specifically stands out: compress the videos to a lower resolution and delete the content after the walkthrough.

**However**, in this scenario, I want to maintain the highest quality of video possible. The app's walkthrough has turned out very nicely and, although it does take up 147MB on launch, the HD screen capture really brings the whole thing together and makes it look professional. In the past, I have used 480p video for walkthrough intros and it looked like a low quality recording. The 1080p video used in this walkthrough, however, looks lifelike – almost as if the app is being automated right before their eyes.

In conclusion, my question to you: *How would you go about implementing these videos in the walkthrough, assuming that compression (or at least 'reduced quality compression') is out of the equation?*

EDIT: A buffer screen/download progress view is possible (until the content has been downloaded), assuming the wait doesn't surpass a ridiculous amount of time.

Comment: cant you just add a youtube player in your app? Or any url owned by foreign web server that can manage playing

Comment: @AkshanshThakur that's definitely a possibility! I haven't tested the quality of streaming a 1080p screen capture from YouTube to an iOS device. As for a web server, I could possibly stream it from a VPS that I own with DreamHost – not sure about the speed, however.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089651/ios-strategies-for-downloading-very-large-data-from-web

Comment: Yeah, you can embed videos pretty seamlessly in your app. It doesn’t even look like it’s a foreign player. You just need to do some research and make a good choice for that route. And for sure, most apps handle larger flies through proper management of url paths